# Powershell: how find all JSON objects containing a specific pair of key:value and iterate all of them?

Tags: json, powershell

I am building a script to repair a SQLite database. One of the fields contains a fairly large string containing a JSON structure.

Inside the structure, there is an array of "items" built like this:

```json
    ...
    },
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 001,
        "Model": {
          "modelname": "Model1"
        },
        ...
        "location": null,
        ...
      },
      {
        "id": 002,
        "Model": {
          "modelname": "Model2"
        },
        ...
        "location": "1020",
        ...
      },
      {
        "id": 003,
        "Model": {
          "modelname": "Model3"
        },
        ...
        "location": null,
        ...
      },
      ...
    ],
```

What I need is to find all items with `"location": null` and not `"modelname": "Model3"` (so, in this example, I will get just the item with `"id": 001`), and then iterate them to edit the "location" property.

I am not really an expert in PowerShell, so I do not know what objects, or array of objects I could get and use.

How can I find the items I need and iterate all of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PowerShell, you can use the ConvertFrom-Json cmdlet to convert the JSON string into an object, and then use PowerShell's array filtering and iteration capabilities to achieve your goal. Here's an example script that demonstrates how to accomplish this:

```
# Assuming you have the JSON string stored in a variable called $jsonString
    $jsonString = '{
      "items": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "Model": {
            "modelname": "Model1"
          },
          "location": null
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "Model": {
            "modelname": "Model2"
          },
          "location": "1020"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "Model": {
            "modelname": "Model3"
          },
          "location": null
        }
      ]
    }'
    
    # Convert the JSON string to an object
    $jsonObject = $jsonString | ConvertFrom-Json
    
    # Filter the items based on the conditions you specified
    $filteredItems = $jsonObject.items | Where-Object { $_.location -eq $null -and $_.Model.modelname -ne "Model3" }
    
    # Iterate over the filtered items and update the "location" property
    foreach ($item in $filteredItems) {
      $item.location = "new_location_value"
    }
    
    # Convert the modified object back to JSON
    $modifiedJsonString = $jsonObject | ConvertTo-Json
    
    # Output the modified JSON string
    Write-Host $modifiedJsonString
```

In this script, we first convert the JSON string to an object using ConvertFrom-Json and store it in the `$jsonObject` variable. Then, we filter the items array based on the conditions you specified using the Where-Object cmdlet, and store the filtered items in the `$filteredItems` variable.

Next, we iterate over the filtered items using a `foreach` loop and update the `location` property to the desired value. Finally, we convert the modified object back to a JSON string using `ConvertTo-Json` and output the modified JSON string.

Note that you should replace "`new_location_value`" with the actual value you want to set for the location property.

This script should help you find the items you need and iterate over them to edit the location property.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The "Filter" and the "Iterate" lines were exactly what i needed.
Thansks for the code and the detailed explanation.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow.  It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since both of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.